# How can I see total Stream.Publish / Feed Dialog posts that contain a user-filled "message" parameter?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, analytics, facebook-insights

Can I use the Insights FQL table or Open Graph endpoint for my app to check:

- Number of publishes of Feed Stories, Open Graph that have an attached User Message
- Number of impressions of ""
- Number of referrals from ""

This would be helpful for understanding how many users opt to take advantage of this feature and the impact it has on the CTR, but I'm not sure if it's available.